# Is there a way to use a number other than 1 for the input to continue the program? It doesnt seem to be recognizing the issues i'm having

Tags: java

So i'm working on a card game where it's almost like rock paper scissors. here's the rules, emperor beats citizen, citizen beats slave, and slave beats emperor. there's a side with 4 citizens and a slave and the other side plays with 4 citizens and an emperor. I have set number values equal to each of the cards but for some reason I cannot seem to make the program continue without using 1 to play the emperor.

```
public static void emperorsTurn() {
    Random cards = new Random();
    int numberx = 0;
    for (int counter = 1; counter <= 3; counter++) {
        numberx = 1 + cards.nextInt(5);
    }

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please pick the card you are playing. \n 
                        if you are playing the Emperor press 1, 
                        if you are playing the citizen press 2");
    int eOS = sc.nextInt(); //fix the input

    if (eOS == 1 && numberx == 2) {
        System.out.println("you have played the emperor! \n 
                            the emperor defeats the citizen");
    }
    if (eOS == 1 && numberx == 1) {
        System.out.println("you have played the emperor! \n 
                            the emperor is defeated by the slave");

        if (eOS == 2 && numberx == 1) {
            System.out.println("you have played the citizen, this defeats the slave");

            if (eOS == 2 && numberx == 2) {
                System.out.println("you have played the citizen, this ties with the citizen");

                if (eOS == 2 && numberx == 3) {
                    System.out.println("you have played the citizen, this defeats the slave"); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you wrote inside `if (eOS == 1 && numberx == 1) {` dosen't make any sense, all the nested `if` blocks inside this block will never execute because it demands `eOS` to be `2` where it is always `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because this part of the code (commented) will never be executed since eOs must always be 1. The if condition will always fail if eOs is any other number:

```
if (eOS == 1 && numberx == 1) {
        System.out.println("you have played the emperor! \n the emperor 
 is defeated by the slave");

        /*if (eOS == 2 && numberx == 1) {
            System.out.println("you have played the citizen, this 
 defeats the slave");

            if (eOS == 2 && numberx == 2) {
                System.out.println("you have played the citizen, this 
 ties with the citizen");


                if (eOS == 2 && numberx == 3) {
                    System.out.println("you have played the citizen, 
 this defeats the slave");*/


 }}}}}
```

To achieve what you want, you must rewrite your code to be:

```
if (eOS == 1 && numberx == 1) {
        System.out.println("you have played the emperor! \n the emperor 
 is defeated by the slave");

}
else if (eOS == 2) 
{
        if (numberx == 1) {
             System.out.println("you have played the citizen, this 
             defeats the slave");
        }
        else if (numberx == 2) {
             System.out.println("you have played the citizen, this 
             ties with the citizen");
        }

        else if (numberx == 3) {
              System.out.println("you have played the citizen, 
           this defeats the slave");
        }
        else
        {
             //print out something else if number is not 1,2 or 3
        }
}
```

OR you can do it as:

```
switch(eOs)
{
     case 1:
         if(numberx == 1) {
             System.out.println("you have played the emperor! \n the emperor 
            is defeated by the slave");
         }
       break;
     case 2:
        if (numberx == 1) {
             System.out.println("you have played the citizen, this 
             defeats the slave");
        }
        else if (numberx == 2) {
             System.out.println("you have played the citizen, this 
             ties with the citizen");
        }

        else if (numberx == 3) {
              System.out.println("you have played the citizen, 
           this defeats the slave");
         }
        else
        {
             //print out something else if number is not 1,2 or 3
        }
       break;
}
```

**EDIT**

Also, I would suggest that if you are going to have a combination of

```
  if(eOS ==1 && numberx== //some other values apart from 1)
  {

  }
```

you break it down since numberx is randomized and can have other values other than 1, to be like:

```
   if (eOS == 1) {
       if(numberx==1)
       {
            //print out something; 
       } 

       else if(numberx==//another value e.g. 2)
       {
           //print out something else;
       }

       else{
           //
       }
    }
    else if(eOS==2)//the rest of the code
```

Comment: You're  welcome. You can also tick the answer to accept it if it has solved the issue you are facing.